# upgrade python offline - ubuntu apt

Tags: python, ubuntu, offline, apt

I have an Ubuntu VM without internet access.  It currently has Python 3.10 installed but I want to update to Python 3.11 (the latest at the time of this post).

On a machine with internet access, I used `apt` to download Python3.11.

```
mkdir python_3.11
apt-get --download-only -o Dir::Cache="./python_3.11/" -o Dir::Cache::archives="./python_3.11/" install python3.11

$ ls python_3.11
libpython3.11-minimal_3.11.0~rc1-1~22.04_amd64.deb  pkgcache.bin
libpython3.11-stdlib_3.11.0~rc1-1~22.04_amd64.deb   python3.11-minimal_3.11.0~rc1-1~22.04_amd64.deb
lock                                                python3.11_3.11.0~rc1-1~22.04_amd64.deb
partial                                             srcpkgcache.bin
```

After transferring the files onto the VM, I tried running `sudo dpkg -i` on each of the files. This eventually "installed" them but opening a python shell still shows the old 3.10 version.  `/usr/bin/python3` still points to `/usr/bin/python3.10` and this is no `/usr/bin/python3.11`.

**Another thing I've tried**

```
# on the machine im trying to install
sudo apt-get update -oDir::Cache::archives="/path/to/downloaded/packages" --no-install-recommends --no-download
sudo apt-get -oDir::Cache::archives="/path/to/downloaded/packages" --no-install-recommends --no-download install python3.11-minimal
```

This ends up returning

> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I've since added the following to the download command. `python3.11-minimal libpython3.11-stdlib python3.11 libpython3.11-minimal python3.11-venv python3.11-doc binfmt-support python3-pip-whl python3-setuptools-whl`. During the install, I'm still getting the same error message on "Unable to fetch some archives".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 commands that need to be run.  I'm not 100% sure the first one (the update) is necessary. It is important that the paths are absolute. Assuming the required packages have been downloaded, it should install.

```
apt-get -oDir::Cache::archives="/absolute/path/"  -oDir::Cache="/absolute/path" --no-install-recommends --no-download update 
apt-get -oDir::Cache::archives="/absolute/path/"  -oDir::Cache="/absolute/path/" --no-install-recommends --no-download install python3.11
```